# lxml append elements to different file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have two files I am trying to combine.  Im trying to capture specific elements, and append them to the end of another xml file.  So far I got this..

```
from lxml import etree



parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

filename = "/Users/eeamesX/work/data/xmltest/output.xml"
tree = etree.parse(filename, parser)
etree.tostring(tree)

root = tree.getroot()

etree.tostring(root)

allTranscripts = root.findall(".//Speaker")
allTranscripts2 = root.findall(".//Device")


for t in allTranscripts:
    print etree.tostring(t)

for e in allTranscripts2:
    print etree.tostring(e)
```

Now I want to take this which grabs data from file1.xml, and add the data to the end of file2.xml.  Any help!?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Just writing the file? Are there other specifications to how you want to write these?

Comment: The data thats printed, I would like to add that to the end of a pre-existing xml file.  From the terminal, id like to eventually be able to get it like ..python xmlcombine.py  file1.xml file2.xml